# Django: strange filtering Database for None-Values behaviour

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm facing a very strange situation when making a Database Request from Django.
I have a model, `chat`, which has a field named `expired`, which can be `null`.
The goal is to filter all the elements from the Chat-Database where expired is not None.
Running the following quick test:

```
    for chat in Chat.objects.all():
        print(chat.expired is None)
```

gives me:

```
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

So there are Chat-objects which expired-fields are not none.
But when filtering:

```
print(Chat.objects.filter(expired__isnull=False))
```

it gives me:

```
<QuerySet [<Chat: 1, type: G>, <Chat: 2, type: G>, <Chat: 3, type: G>, <Chat: 4, type: G>, <Chat: 5, type: G>, <Chat: 6, type: P>]>
```

while the following:

```
    print(Chat.objects.filter(expired__isnull=True))
```

gives:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Both Query outputs can't be right, since in the first test we can see that there are 6 Chat-objects, not all with expired-fields set to None, but the first Query gives six Elements. The second gets Zero, although there are elements with expired-fields to None. What is the Problem?

**Edit**

The Model:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('P', 'private'),
        ('G', 'group'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="private")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='P')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    expired = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What is the type of `expired` field in your model?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I edited the post, forgot about the field

Comment: its is better to add your model field definition as is , not just the field name

Comment: What DB are you using ? And what do you find if you inspect it manually ?

Answer (score 0):

You tried exact field lookup? Something like this

```
print(Chat.objects.filter(expired__exact=None))
```

Se more in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#id4

Comment: Hello mate, it could be the format of field of table, you can set a date like 1899-01-01 and do something like this Char.objects.filter(expired='1899-01-01')